# Regex: match one or more characters, interspersed with spaces

Tags: regex

Is there a way to build a regular expression, which matches substrings like these (`-` means one and the same character, hyphen, for instance):

```
'-'
' -'
'- --'
' --- '
'- -- ---  '
```

but never simple `'\s+'`?

Comment: Do you mean `[\s-]+`?

Comment: No. This one matches `'   '`, which I'd like to exclude.

Comment: Try `\s*(?:-\s*)+` or `\B(?=\s*-)[\s-]+`?

Comment: `\s*(?:-\s*)+` runs on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) as expected. At least I haven't yet run into a catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match sequences of whitespaces and hyphens with at least 1 hyphen, you may use

```
\s*(?:-\s*)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBc1NV/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:-\s*)+` - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.